# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(filePath) returns null on device, but not on simulator

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, xamarin.ios

I'm using following line to create a PDF reference:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef thePDFDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(filePath);
```

On my simulator, this is working.
But when I deploy this to my device, the call returns "null"

The filePath is exactly the same.
As a test, I'm also printing if the filePath (PDF) exists and it does.

I also checked for case sensitive things.
My device is running iOS 6.1.2 and I'm testing with Simulator 6.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the path you are using?

Comment: It's a directory in my documents folder. For example, on the simulator: /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/70D7F533-A8AD-4C25-9F50-C8578A2B0C67/Documents/3/1001/28302/document.pdf
2013-03-02 22:54:12.473 TestApplication[13395:c07] FILEPATH EXISTS

Comment: Have you solved the issue?